# best way to access mssql database with python 3.3

Tags: python, sql-server, oracle11g

Hi I'm learning python and am trying to leverage it more in my daily coding.  I do allot of work with MSSQL and am a bit a bit spoiled with using C#/LINQ.  What is the most efficient way to access data from MSSQL (or Oracle) using python 3.3 ?

Obviously I know it's a matter of using the right tool for the job, however I would like to be able to push myself to utilize python more even if its not the right tool for a particular job just for the learning experience.

Thanks All ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/). It supports what I think you're trying to do.